# How was this titlebar made?

Tags: android, android-layout

This screen was taken from the Aldiko E book reader. I really love the UI. The book list was probably made from a listview with custom background. But how was the title-bar made? With the shadowing and all?

[image: ScreenShot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was made using the Green Droid library in GitHub. https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid

Answer (score 3):

regarding the shadows if you work with `Paint`

```
paint.setShadowLayer(float radius, float dx, float dy, int color);
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm rather new to all this stuff. Can you please explain a bit more? Or maybe a link to some tutorial. Thank you.

Comment: The topic to look for is `canvas`, there you have a `Paint` that stores color and style. Then you can draw primitives or more with a Paint as parameter. Elements that are drawn like that can have a shadow with this setting.

Answer (score 3):

it looks like `LinearLayout` (having horizontal orientation) with `TextView` having weight of 1 and as mentioned above using the shadow layer.

As for the `Books by Rating`, it could be list header or another View inserted into `LinearLayout` (with vertical orientation). As for the individual item, they all have the same background drawable which is `BitmapDrawable` and also having `BitmapDrawable` for the divider/separator.

Answer (score 3):

also from api level 11 and on you have an element called the Action Bar.  This is going to be a new standard for Android so good to check it out.  See [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) google resource for more info.

Answer (score 2):

The background of the title bar is a nine patch png (.9.png), with trans parent png icons on top.

A 9 patch can be stretched without distortion.

[9 patch tool](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html)